# Tesla coil with flyback transformer and ZVS circuit

Tags: flyback, tesla-coil, zvs

I am new to the field of electronics and I might have some wrong concepts.

I was thinking of designing an old fashioned 'spark gap' Tesla coil.

Materials I have:

- [a flyback transformer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08THVDBRX)
- [a cheap ZVS circuit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08THVDBRX)
- a cardboard tube of dimensions - 3.5 in * 19.5 in

If I want to make a Tesla coil, how many turns do I need on the primary and the secondary? What should be the gap for the spark gap? What capacitors should I use? What will be the frequency of the Tesla coil?  I am confused by all these questions. Could someone help me out?

Comment: A spark gap Tesla coil wouldn't need a zero voltage switching module.

Comment: i am actually using the zvs switching module as a driver for my flyback –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://classictesla.com/home/javatc3d/ . JavaTC is one of the most popular Tesla Coil design tools out there and I highly recommend it. It will help you determine resonant frequency, etc. based on your coil dimensions and wire size. As for the ratio between the primary and secondary, for a Tesla coil that is less crucial. Generally you should shoot for around 100 turns on the secondary. Primary turns are tuned to match the resonant frequency of the secondary and topload.

Comment: thank you for your help !!